# Is there a limit to how many channels can be open per session in JSch?

Tags: jsch

Is there a limit to how many channels can be open per session in JSch ? The cannels I am trying to open are of type "ChannelShell"

I get an "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened." exception when I try to open the eleventh channel i.e. channel[10]  Does this mean that I can have up to 10 channels per session?

P.S. I dont understand how to meet stackoverflow's quality standards.

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSH's sshd had such a restriction to allow only 10 channels simultaneously,
and recent its sshd has introduced the flag 'MaxSession' to sshd_config.

Refer to "man sshd_config",

```
 MaxSessions
         Specifies the maximum number of open sessions permitted per net-
         work connection.  The default is 10.
```

Comment: Jsch is a complete SSH2 implementation and not a just a wrapper to Linux native ssh. 

Thus, it does not directly depends on sshd_config information or any other ssh package installed.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a limit (other then by the available memory/thread count in your VM, Integer.MAX_VALUE and what the server supports).

I think I've seen a similar error lately (with a single channel, though) - the reason was some race condition, and it was solved in the latest version (0.1.45-RC4, [linked from the mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4DDCFD09.1060000@gmx.de&forum_name=jsch-users)).

Try replacing your jsch.jar with the latest one, and check if the problem still appears. (It looks like [0.1.45-RC5](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/jsch-0.1.45-rc5.zip) is the latest.) If it still occurs, try to create a minimal example so we can reproduce it.

Comment: can I get just the .jar from somewhere? cant figure out how to import the classes

Comment: well, I read what it is and... I think for now I'll just generate more sessions as I need them. using sessionsNeeded = (channels needed/10); if(channelsNeeded%10 != 0) sessionsNeeded++;  when I am done if I got some more time, I can get back and try to figure out the bottom of it.